# Auto answering multiple prompts of a bash command in (Bash/Docker RUN) non interactively

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

There are ways to automatically answer -y in bash commands for example like

```
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
```

but I'm having this case I want to run

```
 dpkg --install someDebianpackage.deb && apt install --assume-yes --fix-broken
```

It actually answers y for the immediate prompt given by it but in the later stage it asks me to configure geographic are with answer 6

[image]

and after that again I want to answer the command with 20 for the city corresponding to timezone

[image]

and then again with answer 31 and then 1 as same as above for different questions.

What I want to know is to run this command as single command in a non-interactive way. ( I'm hoping to **make a docker file** and put the above command along with  some other commands that can be chained with ***`&&`*** in a **RUN Command** for example like

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install sudo && "the above command along with their answers" && "some other command"
```

I would highly appreciate some guidance over this

Comment: What is the specific command that is asking you those answers? Do you actually have a Dockerfile sketch that you can share?

Comment: I updated the question with what I was trying to run. It worked with @Nick 's answer below by running the command as DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install --assume-yes xfce4 desktop-base

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you can auto-answer prompts with a tool like [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). However, that's usually much more difficult than getting the program to stop asking you questions.

I'm not sure why apt is asking for your timezone, but I suspect that you're pulling in the tzdata package somehow, which wants to configure your timezone. To avoid these questions, you should set the frontend to non-interactive:

> To run `dpkg` (behind other tools like Apt) without interactive
> dialogue, you can set one environment variable as
>
> ```
> DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
> ```

([Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1013396/100386).)

In a Dockerfile, you can set an environment variable like this:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```